# Insert session userdata into a new database in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

How would I go about inserting the session userdate `id` into my new table using the form I have in my view so that I may use the `id` as a foreign key?

**Controller:**

```
function validate_credentials() {
    $this->load->model('member_model');
    $query = $this->member_model->validate();
    if ($query) { // if user credentials validate the user session start
        $data = array(
            'username' => $query->username,
            'id' => $query->id,
            'first_name'=>$query->first_name,
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);

        redirect('members/members_area');
    } else {
        $this->index();
        echo 'Incorrect Password or Username';
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
echo form_open('banks/create_bank');
echo form_input('bank_name', set_value('bank_name', 'Account Name'));
echo form_input('interest', set_value('interest', 'Interest'));
echo form_input('start_amount', set_value('start_amount', 'Starting Balance'));
echo form_input('length', set_value('length', 'Length'));
echo form_submit('submit', 'Create Account')
echo validation_errors('<p class="error"/>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
echo form_open('banks/create_bank');
echo form_input('bank_name', set_value('bank_name', 'Account Name'));
echo form_input('interest', set_value('interest', 'Interest'));
echo form_input('start_amount', set_value('start_amount', 'Starting Balance'));  
echo form_input('length', set_value('length', 'Length'));

**echo form_input('id', set_value('id', $this->session->userdata('id'));**

echo form_submit('submit', 'Create Account')
echo validation_errors('<p class="error"/>');
```

Note : where 'id' in first parameter of form_input function can be replace by any name you want to pass when form will be submit.

Comment: Thank you, on the move atm, but when I'm home il test this.

Comment: Ps, is there not a braket missing, not even at CB any more and still helping, thanks Shiv

Comment: with this code user can change the user_id that is being saved in the db.

Comment: @Dray i did not use it in my view, I used in my model so the user can not alter the ID going in the db

Comment: @Beep well that is good but you should not accept answers which are misleading(working but misleading) , No offence.

Answer (score 0):

In the method used in the controller `banks` where you handle the posted data from the from.

add something like this:

```
$data = array('bank_name' => $this->input->post('bank_name'), // add more post data

              'id' => $this->session->userdata('id') ); //this will take the 
                                                 //value 'id' from session
```

and pass it to your respective model.

Comment: Thank you, away from PC atm but will try it when home

Comment: Hmm, so this will take the value of ID from table 1 and post the ID in table 2. Will the column in table 2 have to be a foreign key ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say, but the ID is taken from session; The value that you set when a user logs in using `$this->session->set_userdata();`